# How Do I write files to removable SD card (not external SD card) in KitKat?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Is there any method to get path to removable SD - card in API > 19 in Android?

Like for external SD card we have `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`
Do we have something like that for removable SD card?

For instance, Galaxy S4 has 2 SD cards - one is built in SD card that is detected by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`
And another is optional, but if user insert it - how do I get a path to it by some method? And if there a method to know if it's mounted - plz also let me know

Comment: Check this out: http://sigidin.blogspot.com/2011/08/check-external-sd-card-on-android.html

Comment: that's great, thanks, but in KitKat this usage was blocked for somewhat reason.

Comment: Why would it be blocked? `/proc/mounts` is always readable. And if you did not have permissions to read/write `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd`, you are screwed anyway

Comment: no, it gives back good directories . for example , /storage/emulated/0 and /storage/sdExtCard. You can write a file to /storage/emulated/0 which in my case is a usual getExternalStorageDirectory() path, but if you try to write to /storage/sdExtCard you'll get an Error back. It works great on all pre-KitKat devices, but on KitKat such access was blocked and I don't know why

Comment: For some devices, fixing this requires rooting the phone http://technofaq.org/posts/2014/04/fixing-external-sd-card-write-issue-on-android-kitkat/. In other words, you might be royally screwed by Google

Comment: Actually, adding permission `WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` might solve this: http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/02/17/external-blues-google-has-brought-big-changes-to-sd-cards-in-kitkat-and-even-samsung-may-be-implementing-them/

Comment: strangely, I can't add it to my manifest - shows me error, like it doesn't know this permission

Comment: Ah, this is system-level permission - only in-rom apps can use it. Blame Google for this. This problem is fixed on Samsung devices and in Cyanogenmod, but not in pure Kitkat

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a reliable way to determine the path to the removable micro SD card. Even getExternalFilesDirs() does not do that on the two of my kitkat devices. You have to ask the user to indicate the exact path.

Answer (score -3):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` gives you just what you want! The term "external" is a bit misleading though.

**EDIT:**

It gives you the directory of *both* sd cards!
You have to chose one by doing:

```
File storageDir = new File("/mnt/");
if(storageDir.isDirectory()){
    String[] dirList = storageDir.list();
    //Select card here
}
```

Comment: it gives me back exactly the built-in SD card, not the removable one. I tested on 2 phones - galaxy S4 and Highscreen omega prime mini - both of them is using built-in SD card with this method instead of removable one

Comment: ok, look at this like this : Some phones or Tabs has a small SD card they put in at factory and they also have an extral slot for an extra SD card. So many devices are now having 2 SD cards - one is like 2GB-8Gb that is not removable, but defines by Android as External SD and another is the one user decides to put in. So, how do I get to 2nd SD card in the device that has 2 SD-crads

Comment: it's not always mnt, it's /storage/ in some cases. P.S. it's not me who is downvoting you

Comment: well manufacturers only make it harder... I have no idea over what I already posted. And who cares about the downvoter, if this guy knew a solution he could write. But he does not...

Comment: I will not downvote this but the answer is wrong. This just does not work on a lot of kitkat devices.

Comment: @greenapps you are right. But the problem is that there is no solution which works for every device. Of course we could pack all soljutions for each device into one code, but this would kill every good coding convention

Comment: @ZerO: no, it is worse than that. For non-rooted "pure" Kitkat devices, solution simply does not exist